# how to load big files ( json or csv ) in spark once

Tags: json, csv, apache-spark, analytics

I do more than one select in two register tables in spark loaded from JSON and CSV. 
but in every select the two files loaded every time, can I load in a global object once?

Comment: you probably looking for `.cache()`

Comment: looking for cache() ???

Comment: one of the files are 30G and second one is 8G, If the file does not fit in the memory it will-will  re-read the file again.

Comment: there is any solution for this problem?

Comment: Which spark version you are using ?

Comment: spark version 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

you can use `persist()` with `StorageLevel` as `MEMORY_AND_DISK`

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
dataFrame.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

check the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

**Note:** this option is more useful, where you have performed some aggregations/tranformation on the input dataset and before going to do next transformation

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space,  when I tried to data frame persist